# Definition of Field Wiring Terminals as in UL 499

Tags: safety, wiring, ul

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me where I can find the definition for "field wiring terminals" as referenced in UL 499 "Standard for Safety Electric Heating Appliances" table 27.1 "Minimum Acceptable Spacings at Field-Wiring Terminals".

My guess is that they're talking about terminals that are intended to be connected/disconnected by the equipment user/operator in the field, but I see no definition that states that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, field wiring is wiring that is connected between equipment items or equipment components that are connected upon installation in the field. Such wiring is generally connected by an installing electrician and run in conduit or other structure used for that purpose in the facility where the equipment is installed. Usually the conductors or cable is supplied by the purchaser of the equipment. Occasionally, equipment is furnished with cables and connectors, but that does not seem to be applicable in this case. I am not familiar with UL 499, but I doubt very much that some other definition pertains to that.

Answer (score 0):

Start off with the definition from NFPA 70.  Then work your way into the product standards.

Heating appliances usually have high temperature terminations based on the testing that was conducted.

However, it sounds like you installed the terminals too close to the wall of the enclosure so the contractor doesn’t have enough wire bending space for the supply conductor.

To answer your question, we need to know the FLA of your equipment.

Keep in mind that there are 2 different tables.  One for field wiring terminations and another for terminals inside the equipment.

Field means supply or interconnecting cables to be ran by a certified contractor.  Not the operator

Conductors are not typically supplied with Permanently connected equipment certified to UL499.  If the manufacturer does, it’s a courtesy gesture for commissioning purposes only.  Example, a flexible conductor cable